# Modal cookie not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cookies

I have a popup modal that uses a cookie to stop it from opening again after the user closes it, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (document.cookie.indexOf("nomodal") <= 0) {
    $("#video-modal").addClass("open");
  };
});

function closeModal() {
  document.cookie = "nomodal=true; max-age=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
  $("#video-modal").removeClass("open");
};
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but doesn't seem to work IE (11). The modal will keep poping up after refresh. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
(document.cookie.indexOf("nomodal") <= 0)
```

should be

```
 (document.cookie.indexOf("nomodal") < 0)
```

indexOf is 0 based and -1 if not found

Comment: Thanks, that works on refresh now. However it stills open if I close and open IE. Any ideas?

Comment: cookies expire automatically unless you add the expires as part of the string.

Comment: Isn't that what max-age is doing in my script? This works in Chrome and Firefox at least.

Comment: what version of IE? Below ver 9 does not support max age. Also try taking the space out between ; and max

Comment: It's happening in IE 11. Space makes no difference. Is there another way to set expiry that I should be using?

Comment: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365  is an invalid date.

Comment: try var d = new Date(Date.now() + 365 *24*60*60*1000);  document.cookie = "nomodal=true; max-age=" + d.getTime();